# Android SAXParser breaks at apostrophe-like character

Tags: java, android

I'm having an issue with the SAXParser in Android.

In the RSS feed I'm trying to parse there is a ’ (this is not a standard apostrophe, but the one that is slanted, the opposite to a backtick) character within a CDATA section, regardless of this I'm getting a parser error:

At line 212, column 26: not well-formed (invalid token)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be a bug in the library, of course, but first check if the encoding of the XML allows this symbol to be there unencoded (i.e. I'd expect it to be multibyte for UTF-8). The parser may be right.

P.S. [This](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) symbol? This one should not be in plain text.

Comment: Yes that's the one, I agree it wouldn't ordinarily allow it but within CDATA it should.

Comment: Make sure that both the xml is written in UTF-8 and that you are opening the file with a reader in the UTF-8 charset.